# Sqlite: order by in subquery "eliminates" results

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite version 3.3.6

There is a table in sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE stats (Date TEXT , Sub TEXT ,  DELAY95TH INT ) ;
```

where each line is :

```
Date      |Sub|Delay
2012-06-25|212|750
2012-06-25|214|1180
2012-06-25|216|14902
```

Task is  to get all records where Sub is from Top 10 by summarized Delay

SQL that does this :

```
Select 
    Date, Sub, Delay 
from 
    stats 
where 
    Sub in (select Sub 
            from stats 
            group by Sub  
            order by SUM(Delay) desc limit 10 ) ;
```

However, it produces no result. Query starts to work as soon as you will delete "order by" clause.

So, for instance  :

```
select 
    Date, Sub, Delay 
from  
    stats  
where
    Sub in (select Sub from stats group by Sub limit 10);
```

works well and produces what is expected.

More than this. There is also table in the same instance :

```
CREATE TABLE data ( Date DATE , Sub INT, Subcont TEXT, Session INT, MsgType TEXT, Score INT);
```

and select similar to problematic one, works fine:

```
select 
    Subcont, MsgType, SUM(Score) 
from
    data 
where 
    Subcont in (select Subcont 
                from data 
                group by Subcont 
                order by sum(Score) desc limit 10) 
group by
    Subcont, MsgType 
order by 
    Subcont, MsgType;
```

It does almost the same:  identifies top 10 Subcont by summarized Score , and displays all records with these Subconts. And it WORKS!

Comment: In your first query, you have ... where sub in (select sub ..); in your second query, you have ... where subm in (select subm ...). Are these simply typos, or do you really have two different columns named sub and subm?

Comment: These are typos. Thanks for pointing out ! Will fix now.

Comment: limit clause don't work in sub query sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found.

I do not know whether it is bug or it  was designed for purpose in sqlite.
The issue is that "order by" is not working in sub-query while operating 
with text field.

After Sub, that was TXT has been converted to INT, next queries started to return expected results:

```
Select Date, Sub , Delay from stats where Sub in (select Sub from stats group by Sub  order by Sub) ; 
Select Date, Sub , Delay from stats where Sub in (select Sub from stats group by Sub  order by SUM(Delay) desc limit 10 ) ;
```

While Sub was TEXT, those queries returned nothing.

The only question remains: what should be  the solution if Sub had some letters inside and convert it to INT would be impossible?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (using SQLite3 version 3.7.5, however). For me, both queries work exactly as expected. Are you 100% sure that you don't have an error elsewhere? Did you try with a completely new SQLite3 database?

Comment: Yep Frank. Fresh DB each run of the script. "Drop if exist" and "Create table" are executed each time i start the script.  You cannot reproduce probably because of sqlite3 version difference. I`m to lazy to check change notes  from 3.3.6 to 3.7.5.  I`m happy that at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I rename the "Date" column to d1 (DATE is a keyword in SQL), I get the expected(?) output:

```
create table stats (d1 date, sub number, delay number);
insert into stats values('2012-06-25', 212, 750);
insert into stats values('2012-06-25', 214, 1180);
insert into stats values('2012-06-25', 216, 14902);

Select D1, Sub , Delay from stats where Sub in (
select Sub from stats group by Sub  order by SUM(Delay) desc limit 10 ) ;
```

returns 3 rows.
So, just rename your Date column and try again :-)

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately no luck. I can also do Select  Sub , Delay from stats ...   and it still provides nothing .